# Flutter: Can't navigate to another page

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-navigation

So, after building my first flutter page, I began working on some other flutter pages for my app. I successfully made two other flutter pages and was able to allows users to navigate between the two, however when I try to allow users to navigate on the original flutter page to any of the other two flutter pages, nothing happens.

Note: the code for navigation seems to be properly written (it works for the other two pages)

Note 2: The line where I navigate to another page is linked to a raised button labeled 'View Record'

Can anyone point anything out in this page that wouldn't allow users to navigate to another page? Thank you!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:faui/faui.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:provendor3/FlutterAuthUiDemoy.dart';
import 'main.dart';

void firestore_page() => runApp(firestore_pagey());
class firestore_pagey extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
  MyApps createState() => MyApps();
 }

class MyApps extends State<firestore_pagey> {

final databaseReference = Firestore.instance;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(home:
  Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('FireStore Demo'),
  ),
  body: Center(
      child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,

    children: <Widget>[

      RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Create Record'),
        onPressed: () {
          createRecord();
        },
      ),
      RaisedButton(
        child: Text('View Record'),
        onPressed: () {
         Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyApp()),
                );
        },
      ),
      RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Update Record'),
        onPressed: () {
          updateData();
        },
      ),
      RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Delete Record'),
        onPressed: () {
          deleteData();
        },
      ),
  new Expanded(child:
    new StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: databaseReference.collection('books').snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) return new Text('Loading...');
      return new ListView(
        children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
          return new ListTile(
            title: new Text(document['title']),
            subtitle: new Text('${document['description']} description'),
          );
        }).toList(),
      );
    },
    )
  )
    ],
  )),
 ) //center
);
}
```

Main.dart

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'FlutterAuthUiDemoy.dart';
  import "firestore_page.dart";

   void main() {  
    runApp(MyApp());
    }


  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp(
       home: Builder(
        builder: (context) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
           title: Text("Page 1"),
        ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            MaterialButton(
              child: Text("Next Page"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FlutterAuthUiDemo()),
                );
              },
              color: Colors.red,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: you have a class called firestore_pagey?

Comment: yes... not my proudest class name, lol

Comment: Are you sure your page name is MyApp?

Comment: Yes! I copied that code exactly from the other page which is linked to MyApp (and its functioning on that page)

Comment: Did you tried to check your onPressed is being called or not ?

Comment: Yes, the onPressed method seems to be working fine other than opening a new page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem appeared to be coming from the page that I was navigating from. I was using a library that seemed to prevent navigation after use, so I removed the library from the page before it and now I can navigate on the page just fine! Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove your MaterialApp then try again? You already have a MaterialApp in your main.dart I assume.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return 
  Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('FireStore Demo'),
 ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately it still doesn't work and I can't navigate to another page from 'firestore_pagey'

Comment: Your all pages are added in your routes right? Can you send main.dart code too please?

Comment: I couldn't see your routes.. Check here to get a little bit more explanation about navigation: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-push-pop-push-1bb718b13c31

Comment: Hm... so I tried adding in the routes, and again, the first two pages work but after navigating to firestore_pagey.dart, I can't seem to navigate to another page